# Fast way to convert Java class to JSON object/format

Tags: java, json

I was looking for a way to get the json format of an java object with "placeholder" values.
For example I have a class like this:

**Employee.java**

```
private String name;
private Integer id;
private List<Address> address;
// Getters //Setters
```

**Address.java**

```
private String buildingName;
private String streetName;
private String zipCode;
```

I want something like this:

```
**convertJavaObjToJson(Employee.class);// My Imaginary jar. (Do we have something like this?)**
```

It should return something like:

```
{
    "name": "String",
    "id": "Integer",
    "address": [{
            "buildingName": "String",
            "streetName": "String",
            "zipCode": "String"
        },
        {
            "buildingName": "String",
            "streetName": "String",
            "zipCode": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know different ways of doing by setting up values in Employee class like this way(one of the way):

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
Address add = new Address();
add.set//BLAH BLAH BLAH
List<Address> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(add);
emp.set //BLAH BLAH BLAH

Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(myEmployee);
```

but I want something that can save my time.

Comment: So you do not really want to convert an object, but convert a class? But how exactly should that work? How would the library know to put 2 empty instances into the array? I don't think there's an automated way. Create your (empty) instances and then use Jackson or Gson to serialize that object graph.

Comment: The easiest way might be using the gson (https://github.com/google/gson) library. Very simple to use and works great for everything.

Comment: Both Gson and Jackson are good options for serializing/deserializing JSON data, simple to use and well documented.refer for comparison and detailed explanation with examples https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson

Comment: Updated my question. I know the different ways how to do it? But in case my class is having a large number of members and I only wants the json format of my class?

Comment: If you only have a few classes you care about and need to maximize speed, write your own hardcoded serialization methods. Libraries will be slower since they use reflection.